# Is the Universal W Apps installable without VS 2015 on Windows 7 machine ?? Or it is included with VS2015 only and minimum Windows 10 PC is required?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I need to run a certain application which needs several dll files like

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL

API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL

EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL

EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-RECTANGLE-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL

EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-1.DLL

EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
and many more

I have installed VS 2013 on my Windows 7 machine but still many api dll files are missing.

Kindly reply if on another system(  Windows 10 ) can I install VS 2015 , will these api files be installed with it or not ??

Does VS 2015 contain many such other API  files ??
Or Some other microsoft package is required ??

What is API Stub Set ??
Closely examining the windows32/downlevel and syswow64 directories, these are Microsoft files , so there is no question of approaching other these files come definitely with certain microsoft software packages and not any other sources

Answer (score 0):

You will need Windows 10 and VS 2015 to start developing UWP app.

Comment: Kindly reply how does c:\windows\winsxs folder takes its content folders and dll files through windows update ?? The mentioned API DLL files which are reported missing are actually located in winsxs folder but the dependancy walker reports them missing from c:\windows\system32 folder. Should I copy or would it not be of any value ??

Answer (score 0):

You need Windows 10 to run Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps.

Running apps is not related to Visual Studio. Installing Visual Studio (or any other package) doesn't affect this.

You can build UWP apps with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7, but will not have the full development experience (such as the designer). You will need to run the app remotely on other systems or devices to test and debug

See the [Visual Studio 2015 Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs) page. Windows Universal is supported on Windows 7 for build on. It is supported on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 with the footnote

> When running on OS earlier than Windows 10, some Visual Studio
>   features for Windows Universal development may be degraded

Comment: Kindly reply how does c:\windows\winsxs folder takes its content folders and dll files through windows update ?? The mentioned API DLL files which are reported missing are actually located in winsxs folder but the dependancy walker reports them missing from c:\windows\system32 folder. Should I copy or would it not be of any value ??  Some of the mentioned files are present in winsxs directory while many others are missing as well